# MVC call a resources file inside a property

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

i want to make the error message displayed localized through showing the error message from a resource file in 'Oninvalid' property and here is my code:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Message, new { @class = "form-control notifi-form-field", @name = "Message", @id = "MessageText",@oninvalid= "this.setCustomValidity('Resources.LayoutResources.RequiredField')"})
```

the  `Resources.LayoutResources.RequiredField` is displayed as it is.
[image: the result shown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a string literal being sent from server-side code to client-side code:

```
"this.setCustomValidity('Resources.LayoutResources.RequiredField')"
```

The reference to the resource needs to be interpreted by the server-side code, so it needs to know that it's not just a string literal.  For example:

```
$"this.setCustomValidity('{Resources.LayoutResources.RequiredField}')"
```

Or with older syntax:

```
"this.setCustomValidity('" + Resources.LayoutResources.RequiredField + "')"
```

Note that the single-quotes are still there for the resulting client-side code to be valid after the server-side code emits the string value.